# How to detach/disable a buffer-update callback in nvim

Tags: neovim, vimscript, lua

In vim, we can implement a vim script, which monitors text changes in details, with `listener_add()`, `listener_remove()`, `listener_flush()`. In nvim, `nvim_buf_attach()` is available to attach a callback. And I thought I could detach it with `nvim_buf_detach()` but it looks like not implemented as Lua callback.

I am looking for how to detach/disable the callback in nvim.

```
:h nvim_buf_attach
• on_lines: Lua callback invoked on change. Return `true` to detach.
```

```
:h api-lua-detach
In-process Lua callbacks can detach by returning `true`. This will detach all callbacks attached with the same nvim_buf_attach() call.
```

So returning 'true' might be a solution but I am not sure how to implement it.
Does anyone have a good idea?